# FireBase Ping delayed

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the firebase SDK integrated in my system and is taking live traffic now.
I`m basically using FCM for sending simple DataMessages to the app. 
We are seeing inconsistency in the time taken for the ping to reach the device, for instance 3 pings are sent for 3 consecutive update actions out of which 2 pings were received immediately, but the third one took around 5 minutes to reach the device.

Do we have a control on the SLA of a firebase ping, can we fine tune and reduce the delay in recieving the Firebase pings on the app?

Comment: Set priority to high and TTL to 0, this will reduce delay, but do not eliminate it

Comment: Thanks, was wondering could this be a thread issue, I`m not explicitly assigning a ThreadManager to the FireBaseOptions, in that case what is the max pool size set  in the executor?

Comment: I don't know, I don't used fcm in java backend